# Moment js Deprecation warning even after converting to ISO format. I converted into ISO format and still it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info. Arguments: [0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: true, _useUTC: true, _l: undefined, _i: 2016-9-26 19:30, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]

```
  this.leaveStartDate = '02/04/2020';
  this.minStartDate = '01/04/2020';

  let leaveStartDate = moment(new Date(this.leaveStartDate).toISOString()).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
  let leaveMetaStartDate = moment(new Date(this.minStartDate).toISOString()).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
  let compareStartDate = moment(leaveStartDate).isAfter(leaveMetaStartDate);
```

Could you please let me know if i'm doing something wrong. i strongly feel, it shows waning in this line `let compareStartDate = moment(leaveStartDate).isAfter(leaveMetaStartDate);`

Comment: Can you add `leaveStartDate` and `leaveMetaStartDate` values in your question it will help what actual values they contain which causing that warning?

Comment: @KamranKhatti, values updated in the question.

Answer (score 1):

as per documentation on github, to work around this issue, specify a format for the string being passed to moment() not using format()

```
  this.leaveStartDate = '02/04/2020';
  this.minStartDate = '01/04/2020';

  let leaveStartDate = moment(new Date(this.leaveStartDate).toISOString(),'MM/DD/YYYY');
  let leaveMetaStartDate = moment(new Date(this.minStartDate).toISOString(),'MM/DD/YYYY');
  let compareStartDate = moment(leaveStartDate).isAfter(leaveMetaStartDate);
```

else you can do this way

```
  this.leaveStartDate = '02/04/2020';
  this.minStartDate = '01/04/2020';

  let leaveStartDate = moment(new Date(this.leaveStartDate).toISOString());
  console.log(leaveStartDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));//format it after creating moment object no issues.
  let leaveMetaStartDate = moment(new Date(this.minStartDate).toISOString())
  console.log(leaveMetaStartDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
  let compareStartDate = moment(leaveStartDate).isAfter(leaveMetaStartDate);
```

[image]

Comment: I tried the above way but seems not working.. throwing following error ```error- TS2322 type moment is not assignable to type string```

Comment: check screenshot i added, I am not getting any warning or error in console. is it because of specific version you are getting error? can you share more detail?